# Import/Update data from Excel to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012-express

I'm converting a database from Excel onto MS SQL server and am basically clueless.

The Excel file has column headings of *GroupID, Name, Members, Remarks*

The SQL table has the same fields.

When I update the SQL some records are totally new, so need to be appended, others need a column or two updated, while most records need nothing at all.  So far I've taken the lazy way out & truncated the file & appended everything back in, but what's the **proper** way?

Comment: Import the file as a separate table and you can do all your updates from there. Depending on your version of SQL server you may be able to use the MERGE statement. It shouldn't take too long to knock up an insert, and an update statement.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse That should probably be an answer, you know, since it is an answer (and a good one at that) and all.

Comment: Fair enough, I've made this an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import the file as a separate table and you can do all your updates from there. Depending on your version of SQL server you may be able to use the [MERGE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37172/Merge-Statement-in-SQL-Server-2008) statement. It shouldn't take too long to knock up an insert, and an update statement.

Something like this for the update:

```
UPDATE o
SET    name = i.name
FROM   originaltablename o
       INNER JOIN importedexceltablename i
           ON o.GroupID = i.GroupID
WHERE  o.name <> i.name
```

And something like this for the insert:

```
INSERT INTO originaltablename
SELECT i.*
FROM   importedexceltablename i
       LEFT JOIN originaltablename o
           ON o.GroupID = i.GroupID
WHERE  o.GroupID IS NULL
```

Be careful though, this is just an example to get you going as you haven't given enough information for a proper solution.

Comment: Thank you much!  That worked fine the other day, but seems to be moofing today for some reason I keep getting an **"Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 3, Invalid object name 'o'." error

The complete code I'm using is:

`USE [Boats]
--select * from [dbo].[Groups] as o


--SELECT * 
--  FROM [dbo].[Groups$] as i
------  WHERE  ID is null;
GO


INSERT INTO o
SELECT i.*
FROM   [dbo].[ImportGrp] i
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Groups] o
           ON o.ID = i.ID
WHERE  o.ID IS NULL

PRINT 'Number of rows added is ' + CAST(@@ROWCOUNT as char(6));

`

Comment: Try changing the line "INSERT INTO o" so that it reads "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Groups]"